# How do I use which(1) with the system's default $PATH?

Tags: environment-variables, path, which

I would like to use `which` with the system's default path, ignoring any embellishments from the user's shell configuration files.

#### Motivation

I am attempting to write a script to find the system's Ruby binary. Many Ruby developers use a Ruby version manager, which adds something like `~/.rvm/bin` to the start of their `$PATH`. I want to bypass this and use the version of Ruby that came with the system, or was installed via the system's package manager.

#### Current solution

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$ env -i sh -c "which ruby"
```

This gives no output, and exits with 1. I would expect it to work though, because the path includes `/usr/bin`, and my system came with a Ruby binary at `/usr/bin/ruby`:

```
$ env -i sh -c "echo \$PATH"
/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:.
$ which -a ruby
# ...
/usr/bin/ruby
```

A few additional details:

- `env -s bash -c "which ruby"` also doesn't find anything.
- `env -i zsh -c "which ruby"` does find `/usr/bin/ruby`, but I can't depend on `zsh`.
- Using the full path to `which` (to make sure I'm using the binary, not the shell built-in) doesn't make any difference.

#### My environment

I'm writing this in Bash on OS X, but would like it to be portable to other shells and operating systems.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a duplicate: I am asking how to find a program within the system's default `$PATH`, not the user's customised `$PATH`. The other question is asking why it is good practice to avoid `which`. Other than involving the same tools, they are completely different questions.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - thanks, I mistakenly thought this was a duplicate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`command -pv` uses a "default value for PATH".

```
$ which ruby
/home/mikel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby

$ command -pv ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work in `zsh`, so based on Stephane's comment, we could use `getconf PATH`:

```
$ PATH=$(getconf PATH) which ruby
```

or use `command -v` in place of `which`, as recommended in [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

```
$ PATH=$(getconf PATH) command -v ruby
```

The downside with these approaches is that if the system administrator installed a system-wide version into say `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt/local/bin`, and all users had that in `PATH` (e.g. via `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment` or similar), the above probably wouldn't find it.

In your specific case, I'd suggest trying something specific to Ruby.  Here's some ideas that might work:

1. Filter out versions in the user's home directory (and relative paths):

   ```
   (
       IFS=:
       set -f
       for dir in $PATH; do
           case $dir/ in
               "$HOME/"*) ;;
               /*/)
                   if [ -f "$dir/ruby" ] && [ -x "$dir/ruby" ]; then
                       printf '%s\n' "$dir/ruby"
                       break
                   fi;;
           esac
       done
   )
   ```
2. Filter out versions in the rvm directory

   ```
   (
       IFS=:
       set -f
       for dir in $PATH; do
           case $dir/ in
               "$rvmpath/"*) ;;
               /*/)
                   if [ -f "$dir/ruby" ] && [ -x "$dir/ruby" ]; then
                       printf '%s\n' "$dir/ruby"
                       break
                   fi;;
           esac
       done
   )
   ```
3. Filter out writeable rubies (last resort, assumes not running as root)

   ```
   (
       IFS=:
       set -f
       for dir in $PATH; do
           case $dir/ in
               /*/)
                   ruby=$dir/ruby
                   if [ -f "$ruby" ] && [ -x "$ruby" ] && [ ! -w "$ruby" ]; then
                       printf '%s\n' "$ruby"
                       break
                   fi;;
           esac
       done
   )
   ```
4. Ask `rvm`, `chruby`, etc.

   ```
   (
       rvm system
       chruby system
       command -v ruby
   )
   ```

The last way makes `rvm` select the default Ruby, but we do it in a subshell, so that the user's preferred Ruby is restored afterwards.  (`chruby` part untested.)

Comment: In theory `command -pv` sounds perfect, but in practice both bash and zsh both return the same result for `command -pv` and `command -v`.

Comment: I also can't use solution 3: This script will be used by ruby developers using rvm and chruby, and by Python developers who don't have rvm installed.

Comment: @georgebrock Even after doing `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`?  Can you double check your `$PATH`?  I definitely get different results for `command -pv` and `command -v`.

Comment: What shell do you use? Under bash (4.2.45) in normal or sh mode, `command -pv ruby` returns the rvm ruby not the system ruby. Under zsh (5.0.2), `command -pv ruby` does not recognise the `-pv` flag and returns `command not found -pv`.

Comment: More precisely, `command -p` uses a value of `$PATH` (see `getconf PATH`) that guarantees POSIX commands are used. Not much to do with the _system's $PATH_ (whatever that is).

Comment: Thanks, `getconf PATH` is another way that is more general than `command -pv`.  Unfortunately it also defaults to `/usr/bin:/bin`, so it wouldn't find packages installed system wide by "make install" or MacPorts, etc.  Added a paragraph pointing out this limitation.

Comment: Another approach could be to select the first `ruby` that is owned by `root`. (`find "$ruby" -prune -user root -print | grep -q .`), as that's how a `ruby` installed by an administrator would typically be set up (though not guaranteed).

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly setting the value of `$PATH` in the sub-shell resolves the problem:

```
env -i sh -c "PATH=\$PATH which ruby"
```

Note that the `$` in `$PATH` is escaped, which means that `$PATH` in the sub-shell command isn't substituted with the parent shell's value of `$PATH` before the command is executed (this could also be achieved using single quotes).

I'd be really interested in knowing why this is necessary in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You generally don't want to use the `which` command. In Bash you should be using the `type` or `command` commands. See this Q&A for reasons why, titled: [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then).

#### Examples

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
```

or this:

```
$ type -a vim
vim is /usr/bin/vim
```

or this:

```
$ command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

or this:

```
$ command -v vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

From Bash's man page.

*excerpt on type*

```
type [-aftpP] name [name ...]
     With no options, indicate how each name would be interpreted if used as a
     command name.  If the -t option is used, type  prints a  string  which  is
     one  of  alias, keyword, function, builtin, or file if name is an alias,
     shell reserved word, function, builtin, or disk file, respectively.  If the
     name is not found, then nothing is  printed, and  an exit status of false
     is returned.  If the -p option is used, type either returns the name of the
     disk file that would be executed if name were specified as a command name,
     or nothing if ``type -t name'' would  not  return file.   The  -P  option
     forces a PATH search for each name, even if ``type -t name'' would not
     return file.  If a command is hashed, -p and -P print the hashed value, not
     necessarily the file that appears first in PATH.  If  the -a option is used,
     type prints all of the places that contain an executable named name.  This
     includes aliases and functions, if and only if the -p option is not also
     used.  The table of hashed commands  is  not  consulted  when using  -a.
     The -f option suppresses shell function lookup, as with the command
     builtin.  type returns true if all of the arguments are found, false if
     any are not found.
```

*excerpt on command*

```
   command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
         Run command with args suppressing the normal shell function lookup.
         Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH are executed.  If
         the -p option is given, the search for command is performed using a
         default value for PATH that  is  guaranteed to find all of the standard
         utilities.  If either the -V or -v option is supplied, a description of
         command is printed.  The -v option causes a single word indicating the
         command or file name used to invoke command to  be displayed; the -V
         option produces a more verbose description.  If the -V or -v option is
         supplied, the exit status is 0 if command was found, and 1 if not.
         If neither option is supplied and an error  occurred  or command
         cannot be  found, the exit status is 127.  Otherwise, the exit status
         of the command builtin is the exit status of command.
```

Comment: The answer you linked to recommends `command -v` which works exactly as I want it to when invoked with `env -i command -v ruby`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Speecify the PATH setting of simply "/usr/bin" (or set PATH to suit) as a parameter to env. env -i ignores the environment it inherits, the following PATH setting will enable which to find /usr/bin/ruby.

```
env -i PATH="/usr/bin" sh -c "which ruby"
```

Comment: Thanks @suspectus, but I'm explicitly trying not to inherit the parent shell's $PATH and use the system's default $PATH instead. The parent shell does have `/usr/bin` in its path, but it also has `~/.rvm/bin` which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: ok understood. Would putting /usr/bin first in the PATH settings (preceding ~/.rvm/bin) achieve what you want?

Comment: I want to be able to find the system's or package manager's ruby binary in this one specific script (in a portable way, which means I can't assume it's in `/usr/bin`), while continuing to use the version from `~/.rvm/bin` in general.

Comment: ok. Answer replaced.

Comment: Thanks. This is still a bit problematic: The sub shell already has a `$PATH` that includes `/usr/bin` (see the part of the question about `env -i sh -c "echo \$PATH"`) but in the sub shell `which` does not work.

Comment: Thanks for your help (up-voted because you got me half way there, and self-answered with the full solution)

Comment: How is this answer different from `echo /usr/bin/ruby`?